# get push notification while the app is not running iPhone

Tags: iphone, push, apple-push-notifications, sandbox

I am working on one iPhone app  which involves a push notification. As I have seen in many documents and tutorials it suggests to register for push notification with in

```
application:(UIApplication *)application 
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

like the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{   
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert| UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|  UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound]; 

    ...
}
```

now the question is, if the app was not running (even in background), when the push come, it cant process the push message, but if I use the push message again from the notification area and lunch the app again, I can get my message.

what I need to do to make my app get the push message even when it lunch for the first time?

Comment: How are you going to send a push to the device before you've registered, got the key & sent it to your server, though?

Comment: if the app was used in the past my server will keep track of the device tokens, so I can send a push even though it is not ruining at that time. But now the issue is when the app launch first time. it is trying to sign up for notification not to process a notification. how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Hang on what? I think you've confused things. See @warrenm's answer.

Comment: Hang on? please read my question properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be conflating the notion of registering for and receiving notifications. It is impossible for an app to receive a push notification before the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` method is called the first time, since this method provides the push token that is used to send push notifications in the first place.

So, you must be talking about receiving notifications under the two separate situations in which they can be delivered: upon initial app launch, and during the execution of the program.

In order to handle notifications of the first type, you must inspect the `options` dictionary sent to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. The following code shows how to route a notification received at launch to the delegate method that is called when a push notification arrives while the app is already running.

Place this in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` override:

```
NSDictionary *pushNotificationPayload = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if(pushNotificationPayload) {
    [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:pushNotificationPayload];
}
```

Comment: yes, this is probably the right solution, I will test it. Thanks Warrenm

Comment: Yes this is the right solution but what if I want alert (`UIAlert` placed inside `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method) will appear when user will click on App Icon, rather than push notification!

Comment: You might have better luck posting this as a new question rather than as a comment on an answer that's more than a year old.